# ad hoc code signing not allowed with SDK 'iOS 8.4'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to run my IOS app on my iphone, I have an apple developer account and I did all the steps to create certificate, When I am trying to run it I have this error message:

> Code Sign error: ad hoc code signing not allowed with SDK 'iOS 8.4'
>
> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Framework'
> in SDK 'iOS 8.4'

Any solution

Edit:
[image]

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8263 check this out it might help

Comment: You do not need ad hoc to run an app on your phone, just build it there with Xcode. The second error message is unusual, check the product type.

Comment: I want to send a copy of app to the customer to check it before publishing @zaph

Comment: Change the question to indicate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, Actually it was from the library, I added it to cocopods and worked well (y)

Answer (score 3):

From XCode select your project file in the navigation area, then go in the Build Settings tab.

Search the 'Code signing' section and check if you have properly set the 'Code Sign Identity' and 'Provisioning profile' properties. In the first one you should read the name identity of the ios program owner, in the second the name of the provisioning profile you create. If you aren't able to select any provisioning profile, copy the one you create in this path:

> ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/

and restart XCode.
This is an example of right configuration:

[image]

Comment: You should post a screen of your configuration to let me help you

Comment: You have to set also the 'Provisiong Profile' field with the Provisioning Profile you created. This provisioning should be in the path I mentioned above.
Compare my Provisioning Profile-> Debug property with your.

Answer (score 0):

Check your provision profile is selected in code singing setting if you selected then clean your project and create archive again.

I think it's helping you

Answer (score 0):

With SDK 'watchOS 3.0' this error occurs because you actually DO need to code sign with SDK 'watchOS 3.0' when you're using Entitlements.

In each targets' General tab in the Signing section you need to enable automatic code signing.