# Code-signing error with Google Drive API for iOS

Tags: ios, google-api, google-drive-api, code-signing

Using iOS-9.2.1, Xcode-7.2.1:

Trying to follow Google's '**Google-Drive API for iOS in Swift**' example (as described here: [Link](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart?ver=swift)), I managed to do all the required steps - but unfortunately at the end when trying to run the new project, I receive a "code signing error" (see picture below...

[image]

Not sure if needed, but under iTunes Developer I created a Wildcard-Provisioning Profile called "com.example.*". (I thought this is necessary since the Google-example works with this Bundle-ID) After having done so in my iTunes-Developer-Console, I went back to XCode and set this com.example.* prov.profile under Target-Build-Setting (as can be seen in the picture below...).

Additionally, my Code-Signing Settings under Build-Settings...

... for the project:
[image]

... for the target:
[image]

Any help appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: Just realized that the simulator works but not the actual iPhone. The question remains - how do you set the Code-Signing Settings for this Google-Drive API correctly ??

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836356/ios8-dynamic-frameworks-codesign-error-code-signing-is-required-for-product and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625320/ad-hoc-code-signing-not-allowed-with-sdk-ios-8-4

Comment: possibly yes - but with the two links you gave here, I do not get to a solution either. What I am looking for is a specific solution to the "code signing error" in the context of the Google Drive API. Any idea what needs to be set for the code-signing settings of the QuickStartApp-example presented by Google ?? Also, I have a hard time finding the FRAMEWORK_PATH within this particular Google-Drive setting ! Any help on this appreciated !!

Comment: Try to look at this [tutorial](https://nghuiqin.wordpress.com/2015/04/09/swift-notes-google-drive-api-library-integration-for-ios/) and [example](https://github.com/baby03201/iOS-Swift-GoogleDriveSample). This might help.

Comment: Thanks abielita! The tutorial is great - but unfortunately already a bit "oldish". Which means, that following the [tutorial](https://nghuiqin.wordpress.com/2015/04/09/swift-notes-google-drive-api-library-integration-for-ios/) you mentioned, one needs to add the following "PREPROCESSOR MACROS" inside project's- and target's-Build-Settings: GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER=0

Comment: And also, even having added the preprocess-macro in order to go with the previous HTTMFetcher (instead of SessionFetcher that does not work) - I am still having an error: i.e. the following code throws an error:  if let files = response.files() where !files.isEmpty {...} Any idea on this ??? Why does the response.files() ... not work ???

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found a solution...

The [step-by-step creation of the Google-Drive API in Swift](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart?ver=swift) does not explain how to code-sing the 3rd-party Google-Framework (GTL.framework) under iOS inside Xcode.

First of all, do not confuse your App code-signing (project and target) with the  additionally needed code-signing of your 3rd party GTL.framework.

The way to proceed:

- select GTLCore project
- under "General" tab, select Team = None
  (here is the catch: even tough the setting Team=None was already set, by selecting it again (=None), there is a hidden change in code-signing settings happening. Frankly, this is not obvious !)

[image]

- to check that there is a change: go to Build Settings --> Code Signing Identity and verify that your Code-Signing is well set to "iOS Developer".
  Again, not only for your project and target but most importantly also for your GTLiOSCore framework !!

[image]

After that, the code-signing error dissappears...